# Choices for 6-digit combination number

Tags: combinatorics

So I'm trying to construct a 6-digit combination number where the digits can be from 0 to 9 and it must have at least one odd and one even number in the combination and there are allowed to be repeats of a number.

My intuition tells me that from the $10^6$ possible combinations the easiest way to work this out would be to take away the combinations where they are all even or all odd.

So $10^6 - 5^6 - 5^6 = 968750$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want 6-digit Number? Or 6- digits combination number?

Comment: @AvinashN My question is about a 6-digit combination number  ie. 016352 is a valid combination

Comment: okay. Then your answer is perfectly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Here is a slower method just to verify things where we let $i$ be the number of odd digits.

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 \binom{6}{i}5^i \cdot 5^{6-i}=5^6
\sum_{i=1}^5\binom{6}{i}=5^6(2^6-2)=10^6-2\cdot 5^6$$